# Exception: Unable to create an instance of "TextBox" in Windows 10 Build 16232

Tags: vb.net, uwp, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml, visual-studio-community

I just did a clean install of [Windows 10 Build 16232](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso) and installed [Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) with the UWP, .NET, and Xamarin "default" packages. I create a blank UWP app, placed a TextBox, and... Got an error.

Here's the XAML :

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox Text="Hello World!"/>
</Grid>
```

Now, for the error :

```
Exception: Unable to create an instance of "TextBox". 

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.InstanceBuilderOperations.InstantiateType(Type type, Boolean supportInternal)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateTargetType(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.LocalInstanceManager.CreateInstance(IInstanceBuilder builder, ViewNode viewNode)

TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)

AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox..ctor()
```

Here's what I tried :

- Debug x86
- Debug ARM
- Debug x64
- Run as Admin
- `chkdsk`
- Reinstall Visual Studio
- Reinstall Windows 10 Build 16232 *(Slow Ring)*
- Install Visual Studio Community 2017
- Uninstall Xamarin
- Upgrade to Windows 10 Build 16241 *(Fast Ring)*

Every other *common* controls **do** work, but not that one. How do I make it work? The problem is only in the designer; I can compile the app just fine.

Comment: You seem to be in a _weird_ situation right now. But why **Preview** version of VS 2017 and **Insider** version of Windows 10. You understand that both are kinda of in a beta state, right? Atleast install the stable version of VS 2017

Comment: @Nobody Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do right now, however, the Community 2017's installation crashes. I have to uninstall everything and re-install only the Community 2017, and it takes a few hours for each modifications.

For your question, I do use every beta software available because I'm having fun testing stuff before they're released (and running into all sort of bugs of course).

Comment: Have fun dealing with this bug then :) Because i don't see a point in coding with beta s/w. Anyways it's your way. But i believe this problem might get solved by using the **stable** build. Hope somebody else from SO would drop a wise solution!

Comment: Install the latest insider build and your issue should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. This is a known issue that has been fixed. As @Justin XL said, you can update your System to [Windows 10 Insider Preview **Build 16251**](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/07/26/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16251-pc-build-15235-mobile) to solve this issue. This is the latest version now. After upgrading, you may need to clean and rebuild your project and reopen your pages, then the `TextBox` should be able to show in XAML Designer with on error.